# Animating circle to square with rounded edges in React-native using `useNativeDriver`

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have a shape that I would like to animate from circular, to a square with rounded edges.

```
            <Animated.View
                style={[{
                      width       : this.state.innerWidth
                    , height      : this.state.innerWidth
                    , borderRadius: this.state.innerRadius
                    , transform   : [{scale:this.state.scale}]
                    , backgroundColor: this.state.color
                    , opacity     : this.state.opacityInner
                }]}
            />
```

I am using `useNativeDriver` because it is much smoother. However, I cannot animate `borderRadius` property since it is not supported by the native driver, and this page [enter link description here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/transforms) does not provide a similar property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to work for `borderRadius`. Native animations may not be supported for properties like height.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { View, Animated } from "react-native";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    borderRadius: new Animated.Value(100)
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    Animated.timing(this.state.borderRadius, {
      toValue: 16,
      duration: 1200,
      useNativeDriver: true
    }).start();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            borderRadius: this.state.borderRadius,
            backgroundColor: "red"
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[image: circle]